# RewriteRule to remove subfolder from all requests

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I've moved my WordPress site both to a new domain and from a subfolder to the domain root. I've working 301 redirects in the htaccess for the old domain, so all requests there are redirected with full path to the new domain. That htaccess does nothing but rewrite the domain, keeping the full request path intact.

On my new domain, requests to the old subfolder are redirected to the domain root by removing the subfolder name. I've also tried to capture the path after the subfolder, and keep that. However, redirecting without the subfolder keeps ending up in the root of the domain.

So, for instance, floriskleijne.nl/site redirects to floriskleijne.com/site, which in turn redirects to floriskleijne.com. So far, so good. But floriskleijne.nl/site/about redirects to floriskleijne.com/site/about, which redirects to floriskleijne.com, and /about gets lost somewhere. For some reason, capturing the path after /site doesn't work.

Also, I'm struggling with the fact that one of the subdirs I want to get rid of used to be called 'wp'. So for that subdir, I need a rule to get rid of it, while still being able to access the wp-admin pages, even though it may be requested with or without trailing slash. A similar challenge holds for site/ which needs to be removed with or without trailing slash, while keeping sitemap.xml accessible.

Here's the htaccess file that fails:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Setting up rewriting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP (temporary until certificate becomes available)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.floriskleijne.nl/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove old subdirs /site/ and /wp/ from URL
RewriteRule ^wp/(.*) http://www.floriskleijne.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) http://www.floriskleijne.nl/$1 [R=301,L]

# WordPress rewrites
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Oh, never mind, I'm an idiot. I entered .nl instead of .com for the redirect target. No wonder it didn't work; some chain/loop redirection was happening. Corrected it to point to .com and everything is now in order.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the logic of the rewrite, but with typos in the redirect targets. I was redirecting to .nl, while I intended to redirect within the .com domain. So the above htaccess file was fine once I'd changed .nl to .com.